# Is there any way to give different names to the members of an array?

Tags: c++

For example I am making a `Pacman` game and I am using a `struct` array to represent the ghosts.

But is there any way to change the `ghost[0]` expression to `Inky` ?

Comment: sounds like you want a map instead of an array

Comment: Don't use a macro...

Comment: How do you want to use this alias? Your question is not very thoroughly described. We have insufficient context to give you a good answer with any degree of confidence.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: That might be better expressed as a member function: `Ghost& Inky() { return ghosts[0]; }`.

Comment: @MSalters depends on where `ghosts` is defined

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are looking for associative array. Associative array is an array that can be accessed with something like association. For example, if you want to access your fruits array and get the apple, you could do: `fruits["apple"]` and get the value, instead of wondering which index the apple was.

If this is what you are really looking for, then in C++ it is called a map. The map is the same as associative array. Take a look onto how to use it.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map

Answer (score 2):

You can define a reference to any item in your `struct` array.

Example:

```
Ghost &inky   = ghosts[0];
Ghost &blinky = ghosts[1];
Ghost &pinky  = ghosts[2];
Ghost &clyde  = ghosts[3];
```

To respect C++ convention, I recommand that all these references are defined with a name that begin with a lower case.

You can then use all these references as normal variables using `.` to call member's functions or to read or assign member's variables.

Example:

```
inky.setBackColor(blue);
inky.remove();
clyde.size += 2;
```

Comment: Note that while this **looks** like it might be terribly inefficient (a reference basically being a sort-of-pointer in one's mind), it's something I've actually used in the past (with much larger arrays, too) and the compiler optimizes the extra indirection out completely, no problem.